# Debezium Change Data Capture (CDC) not working on sql-server 2017

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, sql-server-2017, debezium

After following the instructions listed here [debezium sqlserver connector](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/sqlserver/)  and [how to activate change data capture](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/)

And also making sure that the SQL-Agent is running, debezium is still not working ( streaming data to Kafka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that CDC is broken in the initial release of sql-server 2017

[CDC Bug Report](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073684/fix-change-data-capture-doesn-t-work-in-sql-server-2017)

Updating to cumulative update 4 or higher solves this.

Took a lot of debugging to figure this out, but I learned A LOT about how sql-server works and how the debezium driver works.